# If statement with NSNumber array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nsnumber

All I want to do is check if the `NSNumber`s at the given indexes in the array `gameBoard` add up to 3... I am new to Objective-C and I am unsure of all these `NSNumber`s...  Can someone help me out?

This is what I have.... I presume the `==` is not correct.

```
if ( [[gameBoard objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] + [[gameBoard objectAtIndex:3] integerValue] + [[gameBoard objectAtIndex:6] integerValue]] == 3);
{
    NSLog(@"k");
}
```

Also what is the difference between `intValue` and `integerValue`? I notice they are both options... Should I use one or the other?

Comment: To see the difference between `intValue` and `integerValue`, look at the docs for both.

Comment: You have an extra `]` at the very end of your addition, before the equality comparison operator: `integerValue]] == 3`. Does this code compile? Is that a typo in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon and the extra `]`:

```
if ( [[gameBoard objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] + [[gameBoard objectAtIndex:3] integerValue] + [[gameBoard objectAtIndex:6] integerValue] == 3)
{
    NSLog(@"k");
}
```

Stylistically, you should replace `[gameBoard objectAtIndex:0]`, etc. with `gameBoard[0]`.